# How to find error in code while user input validation in python?

Tags: python, validation, range

I just started to dig myself into python. As always when try to learn a new language, I start with a little game. But this time, I can't see what is gone wrong.
The game is simple. Guess a number between 1 and 100. But before I come to the actual game logic, I want to make sure that the user guessed a number. (instead of an float or string). And the number must be in range between 1 and 100.

For some reason, my approach always tells me that my number is not in the range. And I can't figure out why. So any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
from random import randint as rInt

game = {"winNumber": rInt(1,100), "guessedNumber": 0, "tries": 8, "triesLeft": 8}

def checkInput(uInput):
    """Checks user Inputs if they are valid numbers. Then a second check if the number is in between 1 and 100. Returns TRUE if successfull"""
    try:
        int(uInput)
    except ValueError:
        print("This is not a number!")
    else:
        if uInput not in range(1, 100):
            print("With this number you will definitly loose the game, because it is not between 1 and 100")
        else:
            game["guessedNumber"] = uInput
            return True


while game["triesLeft"] > 0:
    riskyInput = input("Please enter a number between 1 and 100: ")
    if checkInput(riskyInput) == True:
        print (f'The Validator worked. The Player guessed number is: {game["guessedNumber"]}')
    else:
        print ("Something has gone wrong with the validation. We try again")
        continue
```

Comment: Please provide the exact error message you get with the stacktrace if possible. It could help people to understand the problem without having to run the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `try` block converts `uInput` to `int` but throws it away. In the `else` block `uInput` is still a string.

`int(uInput)` should be `uInput = int(uInput)`

Comment: That is a very usefull information. That should have been written in the book that I use to learn python. Thank you man!

Comment: nope.. its "Python Programming: A Practical Introduction To Python Programming For Total Beginners" ISBN-13: 978-1096396598

Answer (score 0):

`uInput` is still a string when you check if it's in the range.

Just convert it to int: `if int(uInput) not in range(1, 100):`

Comment: No need to convert twice. Just store the returned value from the first conversion like my answer shows